# Phoneap 2.9 custom intent on Android not supported from app, only from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

I've got the following situation with a Phonegap 2.9 Android app:
I declared a custom intent so that the app can be opened from a website.
From within the app, I call an external site I control with a form.
On the page of the external site there's a button that is using the custom intent URL to get back to the app.

This construction works for the iOS version of the app, also using Phonegap.

However, for the Android version the popup of Android is saying it doesn't recognizes the custom URL / intent. When I open my browser and navigate to the same external site and pushes the back button with the custom intent-URL, the app gets started.

After searching hours and hours on stackoverflow and the internet in general, I still can't figure out why it isn't working like expected.

Perhaps good to know is that both the app and the external site are using jQuery Mobile.
The external site is opened from the app using

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('https://site.external/');
```

The page is on a HTTPS / SSL location, does this makes any difference?

The manifest looks like this:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.test.app" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity android:name="AppName" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:exported="true"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="customurl" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
            <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
    </activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

The code in the external page is using javascript to prevent possible problems with Google automatic search:

```
window.location = 'customurl://back/';
```

The error I receive when pushing the button with the custom intent:

```
Application Error
The protocol is not supported. (customurl://back/)
```

So, how do I get the external website which was accessed from the app to start the app again, so the user gets back to the app? The only possibility I can think of after searching for hours and hours is to close the app when the user navigates away to the external site.

Comment: I forgot to add: tested on a Sony XPERIA device with Android 4.0.4 and a Samsung device GT-S5300 with Android 2.3.6, both didn't work with the site being called from the app, but only from navigating to the external site in the browser.

Comment: Perhaps some clarification: when I open the external site, the app launches as expected. When I let the app navigate to the external site from within the app, then the app won't open / restart / go back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to set a host in the intent filter also:

```
<data android:scheme="customurl" />
<data android:host="somewebsite.com" />
```

Can you check to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to check it today. As far as I understand the host could also be a wildcard (*), so it would only trigger on the scheme itself?

Comment: Got the time to check out if it made any difference. Unfortunately it didn't. Is it possible that the error is being triggered because the external site is being displayed from within the app, thus being handled by the phonegap "view" and not the native browser?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Never used phonegap before. WebView does have a way that you can override the URL loading though. Perhaps if you can override that you can check for your url scheme and if it is found you could bounce it out to the stock browser, which should then send it back via intent. That is a shot in the dark though on my part.